# How to grab content from web site like this in Perl

Tags: perl, lwp

I want to grab data from the web site :
  http://mops.twse.com.tw/mops/web/t05st03

Set the value of input id "co_id" to 1101

```
<input id="co_id" class="textbox" type="text" onkeydown="{if(event.keyCode==13){ajax1(document.form1,'table01');}}" size="10" value="" name="co_id"></input>
```

and then click the button

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:doAction();hideIt2('quicksearch9');ajax1(document.form1,'table01');" value="搜尋"></input>
```

the web site will show extra data out same web page, that data is what I want to grab.

I wrote a perl code

```
my $url="http://mops.twse.com.tw/mops/web/t05st03"; 
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( );
$mech->get($url);
my $response;
$mech->field(co_id => 1101);
$mech->click_button(name => " 搜尋 ");
$response = $mech->content();
print $response;
```

but it does not get the data in $mech->content

How can I solve it?

Comment: The form action is JavaScript, which isn't supported out of the box. Maybe try http://search.cpan.org/~sprout/WWW-Mechanize-Plugin-JavaScript-0.010/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Plugin/JavaScript.pm

Comment: I have install the Plugin-JavaScript, add $mech->use_plugin('JavaScript');
but report error : Can't locate object method "use_plugin" via package "WWW::Mechanize"

I checked the document of Mechanize, no "use_plugin" found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to emulate JavaScript in your script. I used Firefox's HTTPFox extension to find what info you need to POST:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $url="http://mops.twse.com.tw/mops/web/t05st03";
my $co_id = 1101;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->agent_alias("Windows IE 6");

$mech->get($url);

$mech->post("http://mops.twse.com.tw/mops/web/ajax_t05st03",
        Content => {

            encodeURIComponent => 1,
            step => 1,
            firstin => 1,
            off => 1,
            keyword4 => "",
            code1 => "",
            TYPEK2 => "",
            checkbtn => "",
            queryName => "co_id",
            TYPEK => "all",
            co_id => $co_id,
        });

my $response;

$response = $mech->content();
```

Comment: Very thanks, I tried the code and got the data I need. By the way, HTTPFox is very good add-on tools.